# add elements of scala list

Tags: scala, list, sum

I have the following list in input:

```
val listin= List("banana 20 20", "apple 50 20", "berry 10 10")
```

and I want to sum the 2nd and third element of line in the list , so the output shall look like :

```
val lisout=("banana 20 20 40", "apple 50 20 70", "berry 10 10 20")
```

I wrote the following code

```
 def addInt(a:Int,b:Int):Int={
   a+b
 }

val listout= listin.map(_.split("\\s+")).collect{
  case e=> (e + " " + (addInt(e(1).toInt, e(2).toInt)).toString)}
```

But I am getting the following output/error :

```
List[String] = List([Ljava.lang.String;@7680c376 40, 
[Ljava.lang.String;@bf64054 70, [Ljava.lang.String;@4da833d 20)
```

Any way to this in an elegant way please 
Best regards

Answer (score 1):

The split of a string is an `Array[String]`, so the `e` within your `collect` is also an `Array[String]`. If you call `+` of this with another String, Scala will call `toString` of the array which is an ugly representation.

A most elegant way to do it could be using pattern matching with the `split` function.

```
listin.map { str =>
    val Array(_, numA, numB) = str.split("\\s+")
    str + " " + addInt(numA.toInt, numB.toInt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you `map(_.split(...))`, you obtain a list of arrays, so `e` matches the array with the pieces of strings produced by `split`. The string representation of this array is rather ugly, as you can see. Try something like this instead:

```
listin.map { str =>
  val components = str.split("\\s+")
  str + " " + (components(1).toInt + components(2).toInt)
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a regex to match the entire string, instead of using `split`. This here:

```
val P = """\w+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)""".r
listin.map { case s @ P(x, y) => s + " " + (x.toInt + y.toInt) }
```

gives the same result:

```
List(banana 20 20 40, apple 50 20 70, berry 10 10 20)
```

The pattern `P` means: identifier-symbols, followed by whitespace, followed by digits (first captured group), followed again by whitespace and yet another captured group of digits. In the `map`, the variable `s` matches the entire string, `x` and `y` match the two captured groups with digits.

Answer (score 0):

The output you are getting happens because toString on a list doesn't extract the contents, it outputs the type information.  You might want to play with the mkString function, but that's not the most amazing part of Scala.

You need to discover the true magic of partial functions.

```
val listin= List("banana 20 20", "apple 50 20", "berry 10 10")

val listout= listin.map(_.split("\\s+")).map {
  case Array(a,b,c) => s"$a $b $c ${b.toInt + c.toInt}"
}
```

Being able to unapply the contents of sequences, just like tuples and case classes, is a powerful concept in modern languages.

I also left out the addInt function and gave you an example of string interpolation in exchange. You'll see that by using braces in in an interpolation, you can inject arbitrary code blocks making a lot of string manipulations concise.

Finally, map and collect can be used interchangeably in this case because the partial function really defines an entire function, while collect is great when  you want to skip things that don't match all the cases. If you want to see the map fail, just put "egg 10" in your input list, while collect will just skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got great answers. I just wanted to provide a simple answer only using map and string interpolation

```
listin.map(x => s"$x ${(x.split("\\s+")(1).toInt + x.split("\\s+")(2).toInt)}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a string to array object so you see `OBJECT_HASHCODE SUM` in list.

To get desired output you must add string to string i.e convert the array to string and then add the sum. Using `collect`

```
listInput.map(_.split("\\s+")).collect{
  case e => e.mkString(" ")+" "+(e.apply(1).toInt+e.apply(2).toInt)
}    
//res3: List[String] = List(banana 20 20 40, apple 50 20 70, berry 10 10 20)
```